# Titanium Kitkat/Jellybean slide menu?

Tags: menu, titanium, slide, stock

Is there any way to make a stock android slide menu (like in the Youtube app etc.) with the Titanium SDK? I looked everywhere in the forums but I only found custom slide menus for Alloy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Slider Menu by Matt for both android and iPhone based on classic titanium sdk

https://github.com/appersonlabs/MASlidingMenu

Thanks